# javascript does not scroll to the element on the page

Tags: javascript

I have a `div` on my page which I want to scroll up to after clicking a link in my navigation bar.

I wrote the following JavaScript for that, but it is not working.

```
<script>
    var currentpos = 0;
    function movedown(element){
        window.scrollBy(0,element.offsetHeight);
        delay = window.setInterval('movedown();',100);
        currentpos+=1;
        if(currentpos == element.offsetheight){
            stopscroll();
        }
    }
    function stopscroll(){
         window.clearInterval(delay);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need javascript to accomplish this. You can link directly to an element by its id: <a href="#that-element-id">

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

As noted in @andrewlorente's comment, if you just want it to jump to an element on the page, you can use an anchor link.

```
<a href="#targetElement">See more</a>
```

Downside is that it doesn't scroll - it jumps. It can be forced to scroll with JS though. This is a nice method to allow users to easily bookmark to certain parts on a page though.

---

### JQUERY

If you're willing to use jQuery, this is a function that I use quite a bit to achieve the scrolling that you want.

It uses [jQuery's ScrollTop method](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) passing that into the [animate() method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). The last parameter of `animate()` is `easing`. You can pass in different strings to get different effects. You can view some of the [different easing options](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).

```
/*
 * A scrollTo function that gets passed an ID & an optional offset
 *
 * @param {string}  location ('#resultsTop')
 * @param {integer} offset   (-100)
 */
function scrollTo(location, offset) {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(location).offset().top + (offset || 0) )}, "slow");
    return false;
};
```